# std::out_of_range exception string won't print after compiling code with gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, exception

I'm trying to test the following exception handling code:

```
#include "Array_Template.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Array<int> intArr1;
    //attempt to use out-of-range subscript
    try{
        cout << "\nAttempt to assign 1000 to intArr1[6]" << endl;
        intArr1[6] = 1000;
    } //end try
    catch (const out_of_range &ex){
        cout << "An exception occurred: " << ex.what() << endl;
    } //end catch
    return 0;
} //end main
```

In my Array class template:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

//forward declarations of friend functions as specializations of template
template<typename T> class Array;

template<typename T>
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Array<T> &);
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Array<T> &);

//Array class template
template<typename T>
class Array
{
    friend std::istream &operator>> <>(std::istream &, Array<T> &);
    friend std::ostream &operator<< <>(std::ostream &, const Array<T> &);
public:
    Array(int = 5); //default constructor of array size 5
    Array(const Array<T> &); //copy constructor
    ~Array(); //destructor
    int getSize() const; //return size of array
    const Array<T> &operator=(const Array<T> &); //overloaded assignment operator
    bool operator==(const Array<T> &) const; //overloaded equality operator
    bool operator!=(const Array<T> &r) const //overloaded inequality operator, inline definition
    {
        return !(*this == r); //invokes Array<T>::operator==
    }
    T &operator[](int); //overloaded subscript operator for non-const objects
    T operator[](int) const; //overloaded subscript for const objects
private:
    int size; //pointer-based array size
    T *arrPtr; //pointer to first element of array
}; //end class Array

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(int s)
    :size(s > 0 ? s : 5), arrPtr(new T[size])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        arrPtr[i] = 0;
} //end Array constructor

template<typename T>
//ref return creates a modifiable lvalue
T& Array<T>::operator[](int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) //check if out of bounds
        throw std::out_of_range::out_of_range("index out of range");
    return arrPtr[index]; //ref return
} //end operator[]

template<typename T>
//const ref return creates an rvalue
T Array<T>::operator[](int index) const
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) //check if out of bounds
        throw std::out_of_range::out_of_range("index out of range");
    return arrPtr[index]; //returns copy of this element
} //end operator[]

#endif
```

The program compiles and executes fine in Visual Studio, displaying the correct one-line error message:
[image: out of range error message]

But when when I compile the same program with gcc and runs it, I get the following output:

> *** Error in `./arrays_template': free(): invalid size: 0x0000000001426030 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7364f)[0x7fd7c2e3d64f]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78eae)[0x7fd7c2e42eae]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x79b87)[0x7fd7c2e43b87] ./arrays_template[0x4011a1]
>   ./arrays_template[0x400fc7]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fd7c2debbe5]
>   ./arrays_template[0x400c29]

which is followed by a lengthy memory map trace.
Could someone explain what exactly has occurred here and how to fix it? By fixing I mean how I could get the same error message to be printed as specified in the catch block.

Comment: Show the default constructor definition.

Comment: Side issue: why `T operator[](int) const` and not `const T& operator[](int) const`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow edited and added definition for default constructor.

Comment: @vsoftco I actually wrote the code by referring to a C++ textbook that I'm using. I gather writing the code in the second manner is more efficient as the value is not returned as a copy but as a const ref?

Comment: @bastille77 yes indeed. It will work unless you return a const ref to a local object inside the function. In that case, you end up with a dangling reference (even if const ref bound to temporaries, they only do in a direct assignment, like `const Foo& foo = Foo();`, not when returning a local object from a function, where one more level of indirection is being performed (the temporary is copied into the stack of the caller, then the latter is what you end up with).

Comment: @vsoftco thanks for the explanation. I'll make sure to change it to the more efficient form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is wrong:

```
throw std::out_of_range::out_of_range("index out of range");
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It should be re-written as:

```
throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
```

To call the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) of `std::out_of_range`

---

Also make sure to revise the return type of `operator[](int) const`.

Comment: Thanks as well! Would have chosen your answer if Vlad's didn't come sooner.

Comment: Ohhh, and all the time I was thinking I posted the answer first

Comment: I double checked and it seems you're right. Your answer came in 4 minutes earlier. I guess it's an oversight on my part, my apologies.

Comment: Oh no, you have to just accept the answer most helpful to you not the earliest one. I just thought I should add clarification to the Early comment.

Comment: Tbh both of your answers are nearly identical and both are useful. I wish they could let you select multiple answers, sometimes selecting a single one doesn't seem to make sense when multiple ones are equally good.

Answer (score 2):

Change this statement in the both operators from

```
throw std::out_of_range::out_of_range("index out of range");
```

to

```
throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I had a feeling that these two lines might be the cause of the problem. When I first compiled the code I actually wrote that statement correctly but didn't include the `<stdexcept>` header (a side effect of using MSVS I guess, as code compilation isn't affected by the missing header over there). As a result, gcc threw the error ‘out_of_range’ is not a member of ‘std’. So I went to look up the entry on it on cplusplus.com to see where it is located but misunderstood how the scope should be applied. In any event, many thanks for the help!